# subnetting a class c on a cisco 3825

Tags: networking, cisco, subnet, cidr

I have a class C that I want to better understand before I implement a change.

Right now,

```
ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.192
ip address 192.168.0.65 255.255.255.240 secondary
```

So, where is the 192.168.0.64 address in that mix? 192.168.0.63 should be the broadcast for the first one, and 192.168.0.65 should be the cisco secondary ip.

And ...

How then do I add a /28 (255.255.255.240) right before this segment:

ip address 192.168.0.249 255.255.255.248 secondary

In fact, I'll probably want to add it as a subinterface

Can anyone help me to better understand whats going on and then how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to read this:

[How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work/49836#49836)

Your first subnet-definition has addresses from 192.168.0.0-192.168.0.63. You already knew that.

Your second subnet-definition has addresses from 192.168.0.64-79, with a broadcast of 192.168.0.79. Yes, the definition says .65 in it, but once you've read Evan's excellent article you'll know why the second range starts at .64.

I'm not sure what you're asking for regarding a "/28 right before this segment". The next /28 would be defined:

```
ip address 192.168.0.80 255.255.255.240 secondary
```

And would give a range of .80-.95